# Matching Color in Legend in R plot

Tags: r, colors, graphing, scatter

I'm just starting to use R and I'm trying to make a scatter plot which has different colors based on different attributes.  For example:

```
data.a = 1:5
data.b = 1:5
data.c = c("yes", "no", "yes", "maybe", "no")
plot(data.a, data.b)
```

I want to have a legend which is different colors for points which are "yes", "no", and "maybe" for data.c.  I would also like points to be the colors in the legend.

Answer (score 13):

To elaborate on @MYaseen208's answer: for the legend (given his code) you want something like:

```
legend("topleft", legend=levels(factor(data.c)), text.col=seq_along(levels(factor(data.c))))
```

Comment: I'd like to add that this can be applied to the shapes as well.
legend("topleft", legend=levels(factor(data.c)), pch=20, col=seq_along(levels(factor(data.c))))

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good case for [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/):

```
library("ggplot2")
data_df <- data.frame(a = data.a, b = data.b, c = data.c)
ggplot(data_df, aes(a,b)) + geom_point(aes(color=c))
```

[image: GGPlot2 plot of example data]

Comment: Just a follow-up: How to match text color to dot color? "maybe" in red, "no" in green and "yes" in blue

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
plot(data.a, data.b, col=factor(data.c))
```